# Not able to add Java Certificate and run Maven Project because Java Installed in Program Files (X86) folder

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

I have created Maven Project and added the dependency into the POM File.When i run the project then it is not able to download the Jar Files from the Server because of Java Certification Error.I have tried to add the certificate with below command --> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\"keytool -import -trustcacerts -noprompt -alias hdgr_root_ca -file \fnsk.adroot.cgsf\dfsroot\GB002\DS_BUILD\TYD\nexus_reorg\EHYF_Root_YA.crt -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit.After Executing the command it is giving an error that it is not able to find the path because space present in the folder name Program Files (x86).Can anybody suggest me how to handle this space issue for the folder name as it is not able to find the path.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest appending `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin` to your PATH, then copy your cert into your cacerts folder.  Then cd into your cacerts folder and you should be able to run the command:

`keytool -export -alias hdgr_root_ca -storepass changeit -file EHYF_Root_YA.crt -keystore keystore.jks`

Check the oracle docs for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjrgy/index.html